# Problem faced after removing desktop environment-boot screen changed?

Tags: boot

I installed lubuntu-desktop on Ubuntu to try and later removed all the packages of lubuntu-desktop. The problem occurred that the boot screen become boot screen of lubuntu instead of Ubuntu. Again still there is a option in log in screen to use lubuntu and lubuntu-qt sessions and these two options result only blank screen . So can anyone help me to remove these options from login option and to revert the booting screen back to default Ubuntu boot screen.

Comment: The 'lubuntu' boot screen you are referring to is a `plymouth` screen (used to hide system boot messages) and you can change with `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth; sudo update-initramfs -u`.  You'll probably find a `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` or your desktop-manager may fix your login menu, but you didn't provide version info, so you may need to replace `gdm3` (default for 18.04 LTS) with `lightdm`

Answer (score 0):

You need to have at least one of the *buntu-desktop packages installed.  This pulls in all the other packages required for a desktop session.

So try:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

To get the Ubuntu boot logo, you need to install the package [`plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo)

```
sudo apt install --reinstall plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo
```